# Sun sTax, JAXB and turning off validation against DTD/XSD/schema

Tags: parsing, jboss, jaxb, stax, validating

We are using JAXB in conjuction with sTAX XMLEventReaderAPI to parse and extract data xml retrieved by making a REST Call.

```
InputStream responseStream = response.getEntityInputStream();
    if (responseStream != null) 
    { 

        XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

        // stax API
        XMLEventReader xmler = xmlif.createXMLEventReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

        EventFilter filter = new EventFilter() {
            public boolean accept(XMLEvent event) {
                return event.isStartElement();
            }
        };

       XMLEventReader xmlfer = xmlif.createFilteredReader(xmler, filter);
        xmlfer.nextEvent();

       // use jaxb
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Summary.class);
        Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();


        while (xmlfer.peek() != null) {
            JAXBElement<CustomObject> se = um.unmarshal(xmler,
                    CustomObject.class);
            CustomObject = se.getValue();

        }
        responseStream.close();
    } else {
        logger.error("InputStream response from API is null. No data to process");
    }
    response.close();
}
```

So Basically we parse using sTAX first then unarshall content using JAXB which unmarshalls it the **CustomObject** type. We do other stuff to this **CustomObject** type later.

However we ran into an issue as this chunk of code executes on JBoss AS 6.1.0.Final

We get an exception saying `"The declaration for the entity "HTML.version" must end with '>'"`

It appears that either sTAX or JAXB is validating against a DTD/XSD. The XSD is defined on the same server to which the REST call is made.

Because we are using SUN sTAX and not woodstox that there is no inherent DTD/XSD Validation that comes with it. There is no validation and the error cannot come from the sTAX call

Is that correct ?

If the issue is not validation failure with sTAX it has got to be JAXB.

However I cannot do the following:

```
um.setValidating(false);
```

because setValidating is a deprecated method.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to go about this ? Is our hypothesis correct ?  Is this a known JBoss Issue perhaps ?

Comment: The error message looks like a parser message, are you sure the document is valid?  Could you post the full stack trace and XML document?